# Перехват исключения в Authentication Provider

Tags: java, spring-security, exception-handler

В проекте для перехвата кастомных исключений в контроллерах использую Controller Advice.
Авторизация построена на JWT Токене, соответственно перед непосредственным вызовом контроллера спринг обращается к Authentication Provider и проверяет валидность токена. Т.к это происходит до вызова контроллера, Controller Advice исключения не перехватывает.
Каким образом можно перехватывать кастомные исключения в Authentication Provider'ах?